# Real Positive Zeros of Equation

Tags: roots, estimation, transcendental-equations

During my research on physical problem, I faced the following simple equation:

$r^{2k+1}+ab\,r-a=0$

With:

$-1\leq k\leq1\:,\:0<r\:,\: a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

I need to put bounders on $a,b,k$ such that this equation will have always at least one positive root, also I need to find some rough upper & lower boundary estimation for this positive zero.

We see that if $b=0$ it will be very easy to solve it, anyway this zero will not give us an upper estimation because $ab$ can be positive as much as negative.
Also I thought of putting :

$k=\frac{m}{n}\:,\: m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\:,\: m\leqslant n\:$

and we get the polynomial:

$z^{2m+n}+ab\,z^{n}-a=0\:,\: z=\sqrt[n]{r}$

And using Descartes' Sign Rule tells us only that there will be no positive roots at all only when $a,b<0$ , that's not very useful for me.

So my question is if you can think of any additional tricks/transforms to extract this conditions and the upper bound? also I'm wondering if there is any argumentation on checking the behavior of the polynomial roots (As I did above) and suppose that it will be also true for $k\in\{-1,1\}/\mathbb{\mathbb{Q}}$ ?

Comment: Why don't you try to work with $r^{2k+1} = a -ab r$ in the same way one finds eigenvalues of the mixed bounadry conditions (i.e. $\tan \lambda = \lambda$)?

Comment: Can you please advice where I can read on how to convert it to eigenvalues problems?

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood me. What I meant is to attack the problem in the same way as, for example $\tan \lambda = \lambda$. If you plot $r^{2k+1}$ and $a-ab r$ you can see where are the intersections, which are the roots. For example if $k < -1/2$, then you have an asymptote at $r=0$, and it goes to zero from above as $r\rightarrow \infty$, hence if the straight line $a-ab r$ has a positive slope, there must be a positive solution.

Comment: I see now what you mean, still that can't give me the boundaries... they are more important for me..

Comment: For $k > 0$, you know that $r < r^{2k+1} < r^3$, and you can dominate with the line and the cubic, depending on the sign of $ab$ and if $0 < r < 1$ or $1 < r < \infty$. Negative $k$ is not so straight forward, but the same arguments can be made.

Comment: @Pragabhava : and solving Cubic equation? it's quite complicated to say that this is rough upper bound, maybe other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So you want $y(r)=r^p+Ar+B$ cross the axis on $r>0$, right? Note that this function has at most one positive critical point $R$ found from $pR^{p-1}+A=0$. You can also figure out easily what happens at $r\to 0$ and $r\to+\infty$. Now you get 3 interesting places to look at: $0$, $+\infty$ and $R$ (if the latter exists). If there is a sign change between some 2 of them, you are guaranteed a positive root. The good news is that if all three have the same sign, there is no positive root. So the criterion is complete.

Comment: Oh yes I forget cheeking critical points, that nice, anyway this still can't give me upper & lower bounders....

Comment: Well, all three terms have different growth rates near $0$ and $\infty$, and when one term is twice larger than any of the other two, you certainly don't have a root. This gives you SOME bounds to start with.

Answer (score 0):

In the last two years I have been working with a multi-valued function, which is a modification of Lambert function, $W_q(z)$, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2019.03.046.

In the original problem, R. V. Ramos propose $W_q(z)$ as solution of the problem $$ W_q(z) \cdot \bigg( 1 + (1-q)\cdot W_q(z) \bigg)^\frac{1}{1-q} = z$$

Actually, we have been using Lambert-Tsallis function in many fields, being able to discuss closed-formula of transcendental or polynomial equations in terms of $W_q$.

For sake of simplicity, I decide to change the usual notation, it means, instead of use $W_q(z)$ I will use $W_r(z)$ which is the solution of $$ W_r(z) \cdot \bigg( 1 + \frac{W_r(z)}{r} \bigg)^r = z$$
where $r=1/(q-1)$. From now on I will refer to subindex "r" always.

After a few manipulations and taking in account your conditions ($-1 \leq k \leq 1, (a,b \in R)$ to generate $r>0$), one can show that

$$ r={\bigg[\frac{ab}{2k} \cdot W_{2k}\bigg(\frac{2k}{ab}\cdot (\frac{1}{b})^{2k} \bigg)   \bigg]}^{\frac{1}{2k}}    \  \  \  \  \  (1)$$

As previously said, $W_r(z)$ is a multivalued function. In this way, you have to test which of the solutions found will be a truly solution of your original problem. However, it is possible to set limits and relationship among $a,b,k$.

1. Consider $z>0$, it means, $$\frac{2k}{ab}\cdot (\frac{1}{b})^{2k} >0$$ will generate one positive solution in $W_{2k}(z)$. In your case, you have to impose $$2k,a,b>0$$ you will always have one valid $r>0$.
   Another condition is $$ 2k,a<0, b>0$$

A few values are illustrated below

\begin{matrix}
a & b & 2k & z & W_{2k}(z) & r \\
\mathbf{\pi} & \textbf{+2.0000} & \textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{+0.0277} & \textbf{(+0.02702 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.44050 , +0.00000i)} \\
+3.0000 & +12.0000 & +1.0000 & +0.0023 & (-1.00231 , -0.00000i) & (-36.08314 , -0.00000i) \\ 
\textbf{+3.0000} & \textbf{+12.0000} & \textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{+0.0023} & \textbf{(+0.00231 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.08314 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+4.0000} & \mathbf{\sqrt{2}} & \textbf{+0.6667} & \textbf{+0.0935} & \textbf{(+0.08625 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.62610 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
+3.0000 & +5.0000 & +1.8000 & +0.0066 & (-1.81568 , -0.07798i) & (-0.67940 , -4.47455i) \\ 
+3.0000 & +5.0000 & +1.8000 & +0.0066 & (-1.81568 , +0.07798i) & (-0.67940 , +4.47455i) \\ 
\textbf{+3.0000} & \textbf{+5.0000} & \textbf{+1.8000} & \textbf{+0.0066} & \textbf{(+0.00658 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.19927 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{-5.0000} & \textbf{+2.0000} & \textbf{-0.6000} & \textbf{+0.0909} & \textbf{(+0.08316 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.58045 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{-3.0000} & \textbf{+5.0000} & \textbf{-0.2000} & \textbf{+0.0184} & \textbf{(+0.01805 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.21984 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{-0.5000} & \textbf{+0.5000} & \textbf{-1.4000} & \textbf{+2.1220} & \textbf{(+0.74020 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+4.24369 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\end{matrix}

2. Another possibility is in the range $z_b < z < 0$

with $W_b=-\frac{2k}{2k+1}$ and $z_b=W_b\cdot |W_b|^{2k}$ or

$$2k<-1, a>0 \implies 0< b<b_{Th}, $$
with $b_{Th}=(\frac{2k}{a\cdot z_b})^{1/(2k+1)}$ and it will generate 1 value for $r$

\begin{matrix}
a & b <b_{Th} & 2k & z & W_{2k}(z) & r \\
\textbf{+3.0000} & \textbf{+0.2500} & \textbf{-2.0000} & \textbf{-0.1667} & \textbf{(-19.79796 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+0.36701 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+3.0000} & \textbf{+0.2500} & \textbf{-2.0000} & \textbf{-0.1667} & \textbf{(-0.20204 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+3.63299 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{+0.0494} & \textbf{-1.5000} & \textbf{-0.3333} & \textbf{(-0.52150 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+15.02600 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{+0.0223} & \textbf{-1.2000} & \textbf{-0.5610} & \textbf{(-1.45444 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+20.24825 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{+0.0117} & \textbf{-1.1000} & \textbf{-0.7049} & \textbf{(-2.98443 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+23.05168 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\end{matrix}

$$2k>0, b>0 \implies -\infty< a<a_{Th}, $$

with $a_{Th}=\frac{2k}{z_b\cdot b^{2k+1}})^{1/(2k+1)}$ and it will generate 2 values for $r>0$

\begin{matrix}
b & a <a_{Th} & 2k & z & W_{2k}(z) & r \\
\textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{-19.0047} & \textbf{+0.2200} & \textbf{-0.0825} & \textbf{(-0.21731 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+408.86210 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{-19.0047} & \textbf{+0.2200} & \textbf{-0.0825} & \textbf{(-0.09308 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+8.66697 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{-150.0000} & \textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{-0.1667} & \textbf{(-0.78868 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+23.66025 , +0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{-150.0000} & \textbf{+1.0000} & \textbf{-0.1667} & \textbf{(-0.21132 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+6.33975 , +0.00000i)} \\
+0.2000 & -1265.6250 & +2.0000 & -0.1975 & (-2.55599 , -0.00000i) & (+17.98590 , +0.00000i) \\ 
\textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{-1265.6250} & \textbf{+2.0000} & \textbf{-0.1975} & \textbf{(-1.18262 , +0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+12.23417 , -0.00000i)} \\ 
\textbf{+0.2000} & \textbf{-1265.6250} & \textbf{+2.0000} & \textbf{-0.1975} & \textbf{(-0.26139 , -0.00000i)} & \textbf{(+5.75173 , +0.00000i)} \\  
\end{matrix}

Unfortunately, I have not seen any conditions when $b<0$, no matter values of $k and a$ possible to generate $r>0$